# How to draw signature on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, digital-signature

I'am curruently working to make a signature app in laravel using mainly html and javascript, I'am already abled to draw on a pc but I'am not abled to draw on a moble device. So my question is how am I abled to draw on a mobile device?

This app is going to be used for signing off for delivering packages

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    </head>

    <div class="card-header">
        <h2 class="text-center">Leverings check</h2>
        <a href="{{route('tekenen.home')}}"><div class="btn btn-danger">Pagina terug</div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="painter" name="painter" width="400" height="200" style="position:absolute;top:53%;left:4%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>

    <img id="photo" name="photo" style="position:absolute;top:53%;left:4%;" style="display:none;">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="button"  value="Opslaan" id="btn" size=15" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:80%;left:4%;">
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Leegmaken" id="clr" size="15" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:80%;left:4%;">

    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <td  style="width: 10%">Klant</td>
            <td style="width: 10%">Klant nummer</td>
            <td style="width: 80%">ordernummer</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($order_nummer as $aftekenens)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$aftekenens->klant}}</td>
                <td>{{$aftekenens->klant_nummer}}</td>
                <td>{{$aftekenens->order_nummer}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <form action="{{route('tekenen.store')}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div style="position:absolute;top:40%;left:4%;">
            <label for="coli">Aantal coli('s):</label> <input type="text" id="coli" name="coli" required>
            <br>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="src_image" value="dataURL" id="src_image">
        <input type="hidden" name="photo" id="photo">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_nummer" value="<?php echo $aftekenens->order_nummer;?>">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="button"  value="Opslaan" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:80%;left:17%;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="position:absolute;top:85%;left:4%;">toevoegen</button>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:45%;left: 4%;">
            <label for="ingevulde_naam">Naam:</label>  <input type="text" id="ingevulde_naam" name="ingevulde_naam" required>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute;top:50%;left:4%;">
            Handtekening hier beneden zetten a.u.b. :
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
        </div>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        touchX = 0,
        touchY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;

    function init() {

        canvas = document.getElementById('painter');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, function (e) {     
           findxy('move', e) 
            }, false);

        canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, function (e) {
            findxy('start', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd, function (e) {
            findxy('end', e)
        }, false);

    }

    function draw() {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY,);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY,);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

    }
    function touchStart() {
        getTouchPos();

        draw(touchX, touchY);

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function touchMove(e) {
        getTouchPos(e);
        event.preventDefault();

        draw(touchX,touchY);

    }

    function touchEnd() {
        getTouchPos(e);
        event.preventDefault();

        draw(touchX, touchY);
    }

    function getTouchPos(e) {
        if (!e)

        if(e.touches) {
            if(e.touches.length == 1){
            var touch = e.touches[0];
            touchX=touch.pageX-touch.target.offsetLeft;
            touchY=touch.pageY-touch.target.offsetTop;


            }
        }
    }

    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }

    function erase()
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        document.getElementById("photo").style.display = "none";
    }

    function save() {
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById("photo").style.border = "2px solid";
        document.getElementById("photo").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("photo").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("src_image").value = dataURL;
    }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, a proper mobile app will be more appropriate for a such a solution.

Anyway, there are no mouse events in mobile, only touch events.

Please take a look here as a starting point:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events

And here for a few examples:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/touch#implement-custom-gestures